# Listview1 Keeps on Doubling my Info I put into it and not Clearing it

Tags: vb.net, listview

I hope someone can help, I have been searching for more than a week now on my problem. I have a excel file with lot of info in it, and what I want to do is to is make an interface with a search button. So if I type in the day, month, year it will pull that file for me and view it in Listview. I got that working, but when I change the date ad click my search button, it clears the Listview, and throws the same old search and the new search in Listview.

When I click search, I want it to only show me my new search.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim ListView1 As New ListView

        ' ListView1 = New ListView()
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        ListView1.View = View.Details
        ListView1.GridLines = True
        ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
        ListView1.HideSelection = False
        ListView1.MultiSelect = False


        ListView1.Columns.Add("Description", 160, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        ListView1.Columns.Add("QTY", 160, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        ListView1.Columns.Add("Total", 160, HorizontalAlignment.Left)


        TextBox4.Clear()
        TextBox4.Text = ("d:\test\" + TextBox3.Text + "_" + TextBox2.Text + ".xls")

        If GetInfo() = True Then

            For Each Xitem In ExcelRowList
                Dim lvitem = ListView1.Items.Add(Xitem.C1)
                lvitem.SubItems.AddRange(New String() {Xitem.C2, Xitem.C3})
            Next
        End If
        '######################################## To get Total Amount in Total Box for Day Amount ######################

        Dim dblTotal As Double = 0
        Dim dblTemp As Double

        For Each lvItem As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            If Double.TryParse(lvItem.SubItems(2).Text, dblTemp) Then
                dblTotal += dblTemp
            End If
        Next

        TextBox5.Text = dblTotal

    End Sub


    Private Function GetInfo() As Boolean
        Dim Completed As Boolean = False
        'Open Workbook
        Dim MyExcel As New Application
        MyExcel.Workbooks.Open(TextBox4.Text)
        'Extract Date From Workbook
        MyExcel.Sheets(TextBox1.Text).Activate()
        MyExcel.Range("B2").Activate()

        Dim ThisRow As New ExcelRows

        Do
            If MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value > Nothing Or MyExcel.ActiveCell.Text > Nothing Then

                ThisRow.C1 = MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value
                MyExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

                ThisRow.C2 = MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value
                MyExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate()

                ThisRow.C3 = MyExcel.ActiveCell.Value


                ExcelRowList.Add(ThisRow)

                MyExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(1, -2).Activate()

            Else
                Completed = True


                Exit Do

            End If

        Loop

        'Close Workbook



        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(New Application)
        Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process

        For Each proc In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")

            proc.Kill()
            MyExcel = Nothing
            ThisRow = Nothing
        Next

        Return Completed



    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This `Dim ListView1 As New ListView` creates a new listview each time you call it.  Try putting it at the class level so it only gets called once.  Also clear the columns collection as well as the items collection.

Also try clearing `ExcelRowList` in the `GetInfo` routine

On a side note, the routine where you add the column total up, you could put that right inside the loop where you add the listviewitems, instead of running another loop.

Comment: Hi it still is doing exactly the same, It just keeps on Doubling the Info, Any other suggestions.

Comment: I added another suggestion.